# How Do I Set PHP to Download File to a Specific Directory?

Tags: php, file, curl, download, filepath

I am looking for some general guidance on this one...

I have created a PHP script that uses cURL to download a csv file.  Currently, it downloads the file to my computer when I run the script.  I would like to amend the download path to route it to a directory on my web host.  Is there any easy way to do this with PHP?

Here is a quick summary of the PHP script that downloads the CSV file:

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init(); 
//this is where I submit the form to download the csv file...
curl_close ($ch);  

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file_I_am_downloading.csv"); 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
readfile("http://www.example.com/file_I_am_downloading.csv");
?>
```

To sum this up, I would like the script to be amended so that when I run this PHP file it downloads 'file_I_am_downloading.csv' to a specific directory on my host rather than first downloading to my computer.  Thank you for your time and any direction you can provide is much appreciated.

Comment: If you have fopen wrappers enabled you can simply use the PHP copy command : http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
.... curl setup
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if ($data === FALSE) {
   die(curl_error($ch));
}

// do this, instead of the header/readfile business.
file_put_contents('/some/path/on/your/webhost', $data);
```

Comment: I tried that, but it is giving me an error: Warning: file_put_contents(/file/path/) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied... I assigned 777 to the directory, I am not exactly sure why I am getting the error.  I will keep working with it though.  Thanks for the input :)

Comment: You need to specify a filename, not just a directory. `/some/path/file.txt`

Comment: Awesome!  Worked out great now :) Thanks