# Is there a way to check file editing is finished in google drive and way to upload the file into our custom directory on server

Tags: google-drive-api

Actually i am working on Google drive Api(PHP) I can upload the file into drive and now I want to check that file is editing or not and if file is edited then how we can upload this file to our custom directory with api.

Comment: you can tell when a file was last edited but there is no way of knowing if someone is currently editing a file.

Comment: okay thanks for the reply and how can we upload the drive file to our custom directory automatically

Comment: Have you trying googleing "Google drive API file upload"?

Comment: Yes I have tried but not found any proper solution

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask your question is to broad.

Comment: If your code for checking file is in different server try reading about the document - [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads), after checking the file create a implementation for server to server file transfer. If your code is in the same server, try checking this SO [question - How Do I Set PHP to Download File to a Specific Directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6862666/5995040) Hope this helps.