# PHP - Transfer file from Server to Windows PC

Tags: php, file, ssh, scp, transfer

I have tried a few SSH and SCP snippets to transfer files from a web server to a windows pc and I can't quite get it working. There are a combination of things I believe I need such as firewall permissions, php modules, etc.

What boggles my mind is, it is so easy to ssh to a linux machine because I know the username and password but for Windows, you don't REALLY have a username and sometimes don't even have a password.

That being said, here is what I need to do. I have a linux server online and need to send a XML file to a windows pc. Out of your experiences, what are the best php modules, snippets, and any tips that you followed to achieve this? I believe the IP I would use for my windows machine would be my public ip but what in the world would the password be.. I have no pw on my computer? Do I need extra software installed on my windows pc as well?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into your IP potentially being dynamic.

It sounds like you need a cron job on the web server. You could then set up a FTP/SSH server on your Windows PC to receive the file.

On the other hand if this file is in a website folder which has FTP access. You could FTP to the server from your Windows pc and get the file with an FTP client.

Programs such as FTPBox could sync this for you or Curl from the command line.

With a command line program like Curl on your Windows PC you could set up a cron job on your Windows pc to automate getting this file if you want to do this automatically.

There are a few other options like a virtual linux machine on your windows pc. Then you could SSH from there and set up shared folders etc.

But to put it as simply as my experience has taken me.

- If you have a webserver use FTPS and use a FTP client on your PC.
- or use a command line program like Curl to automate from windows pc

From the server you need a cron job to automate the process, but you need to setup some type of server to receive this reliably. You could have a PHP file call a script file with php exec() depending on your webservers permissions.

Your router and software firewall may need to be configured to allow the ports you use for the transfer.

Easiest option is FTP server on webserver and FTP client on windows machine.

There are a few options, so I hope this has helped somewhat, I haven't taken into account a few things like security, automation, permissions etc. So none of these could be your best option. :)

Hope this helps a bit

Edit: Just to add Windows doesn't come with SSH which might explain some of the username/password issues. When you set up a FTP server on your Windows pc you can set your credentials

Here is a guide for setting up FTP Server on Windows PC 
https://www.howtogeek.com/140352/how-to-host-an-ftp-server-on-windows-with-filezilla/

Once you have a server setup on your pc, if you wish to go down the route of a creating a cron job on your webserver for automation, you will havve your credentials from your server setup.

Comment: @O Grant - Thanks for all of the great ideas. I had actually done everything you said before I read this - regarding the FTP software and making a user name and password, etc. The only issue is that you have to open a port on your router.

Let me give you a scenario so you see what I'm creating... I have an online website where I will have different customers sign into. There is a mini application that allows them to scan a barcode and it sends a file to a folder on their Windows PC. I need a way for them to configure their own settings so it sends to their Windows PC. (more in next comment)

Comment: (continued...) I wish it was as easy as having them enter their IP/User and Password but I would literally have to tell them to download the FTP software, open up firewalls, and most importantly what I CANT tell a customer to so is log into their router and open up a port. I feel like that is such a bad thing to tell your customers. But again.. there is no other way to transfer files to their PC....... Not sure where to go from here because even if they were OK with opening ports on their router, they probably dont even know how to log into the router or know the password!

Comment: I see what you are saying. Would a potential solution be to have your website prompt the user for a download.
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed enter (full message below):

I see what you are saying. Would a potential solution be to have your website prompt the user for a download.
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp
Example: <a href="/images/DownloadFileImageButton.jpg" download="FolderToFile/Filename">

Then depending on whichever file they need, changing the file using a PHP script on the download attribute to change the filename.

Comment: Another solution could be to have a Python script to FTP into your server and get the relevant file and download it to the PC. This option also requires configuration (ie Python on the users PC), so your better off with some sort of prompt on your website. Feel free to message me if you want me to help you out, you still have options for your solution.

Comment: Thanks O Grant, let me check out those suggestions you mentioned. The thing I'm worried about with the website prompt is that the file will be transfered to their Downloads folder I assume? It needs to download to a specific folder that is probably on their desktop

Comment: So I looked into the "html download attribute" but what I found is that it definitely can only download to the Downloads folder so that won't work in my case.

The company/project I'm working on involves a "hot folder" on the desktop (the hot folder has configured actions and stuff so it's important that the file gets sent to their hot folder). 

The file needs to be transferred from the website server to their hot folder on a click of a button. I think the only option is telling them to log into their router to open ports (which again we can't do because of security reasons & liablity).

Comment: Ok i see your issue. You could try this answer from Stack using PHPs CURL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862635/how-do-i-set-php-to-download-file-to-a-specific-directory